# Can you ever drop the first ‘as’ in “as . . . as” constructions?

Tags: comparatives

I have wondered if dropping the first *as* is permissible and grammatical while using comparison:

> Ian Bell was organised and elegant as ever, prospering with several
>   uppercuts over the slips.

I believe ***as* organized and elegant as ever**  is correct, but is the above formulation also acceptable?

Comment: It's not quite the same, though. Unlike in *as cool as a cucumber*. In the instant case, *as* can simply mean 'like': *Ian Bell was organised and elegant like he always is ...* On the other hand, the *as* in *as cool as cucumber* is also sometimes omitted.

Comment: In some circumstances, it often is: Quick as a flash, he ate the daffodil. Mad as a hatter!

Comment: There's more than one way to swing a dead cat:  Ever organized and elegant, Ian Bell prospered with several uppercuts over the slips. (What "uppercuts over the slips" means, I do not know, nor will I expend any energy in finding out!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases, notably when the "as" used interchangeably with "like" in a simile.

For example:

"He is as spry as a mouse."

"He is spry as a mouse."

"He is spry like a mouse."

I would use the first "as" if possible, because it lends a clearer meaning to the sentence. Also, the longer the the first part is, the more it makes sense as you speak it.